# Using addAll with synchronized lists in Java

Tags: java

I have a `List<GameElement>` defined as follows:

```
protected List<GameElement> elements = Collections.synchronizedList(new LinkedList<>());
```

And to add a comma-separated listing of elements to the list, I use the method `addElements`:

```
protected void addElements(GameElement... elements){
    this.elements.addAll(new LinkedList<GameElement>(Arrays.asList(elements)));
}
```

Is there a cleaner way to add elements to `List<GameElement> elements`?

Comment: What is not clean in this? Do you want to make a loop on the elements and add them one-by-one?

Comment: Why do you bother with the `LinkedList` in `addAll`?

Comment: Why not just `this.elements.addAll((Arrays.asList(elements))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to convert the list to LinkedList. addAll gets a Collection, and List implements Collection itself.

```
protected void addElements(GameElement... elements){
    // either:
    this.elements.addAll(Arrays.asList(elements));

    // or as @VGR commented:
    Collections.addAll(this.elements, elements)
}
```

Comment: For some reason, this wasn't working last time I checked; but it works now. Thanks!

Comment: I fixed you compiler :)

Comment: Actually, `Collections.addAll(this.elements, elements)` is preferred.  The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#addAll-java.util.Collection-T...-) claims it can offer a significant performance benefit.